# Show designed map tips instead of the default pop-ups in qgis2web

Tags: qgis, openlayers, html, qgis2web, maptips

I continue designing my customized interactive map using the latest version of qgis2web plug in. In this location, I want to display in the exported qgis2web map the map tips [image]I designed with html in the QGIS 3.26 desktop version instead of the default pop ups that the plug in provides, but I did not reach to edit correctly the script to make them visible. I have exported the map in Openlayers and with the pop-up option uncheked. I have been trying to make the map tips to appear editing the qgis2web.js adding a GetFeatureInfo line on pointer view section and also I tried to add in that same section the line var current map_tip but neither of the two worked.
I attached  the modified script:

```
    var onSingleClick = function(evt) {
    if (doHover) {
        return;
    }
    if (sketch) {
        return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    var popupField;
    var currentmap_tip
    var currentFeature;
    var currentFeatureKeys;
    var clusteredFeatures;
    var popupText = '<ul>';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
```

I also attached an image where it is shown the map tip as it appear in the QGIS desktop version:

[image]

And how it does not appear in  the exported qgis2web:
[image]

Here is the html code I used to desgined the map tip in qgis:

```
<style> 

h3 { margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px; } 

</style> 
 
<div style="width:100;height:100; background-color: lightgrey"> 

<h3>Datos:</h3> 

<b>Nombre: </b>[% "sector" %]<br> 

<br> 

<b>Tipo: </b>[% "tipo_obra" %]<br> 

<br> 

<b>Web: </b>[% "id_obra" %]<br> 

<div>
```